# Can't access a propertu in a JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I want to access a property in a JSON object i'm getting from the wikipedia API.
You can see the object [here](https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=baguette&prop=extracts&exintro&explaintext&redirects&format=json&utf8)

```
{
  "batchcomplete": "",
  "query": {
    "normalized": [
      {
        "from": "baguette",
        "to": "Baguette"
      }
    ],
    "pages": {
      "274152": {
        "pageid": 274152,
        "ns": 0,
        "title": "Baguette",
        "extract": "Une baguette est, dans son sens premier, une tige de bois, de métal, ou de divers autres matériaux ; le mot peut désigner aussi d’autres concepts, notamment par métonymie.\n\n"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I want is : query -> pages -> 274152 -> extract

I can access this value but the problem is I need to know the '274152' value which changes for every object so I'd like a solution to access it which would work for any number.

So the farthest I can go is `obj.query.pages`

Any idea ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
var keys = Object.keys(obj.query.pages);
```

To get array of properties defined in the `pages` object. Then you can basically do `obj.query.pages[keys[i]]` to access `i`-th item in the `pages` object, for example:

```
obj.query.pages[keys[0]].extract
```

Alternatively you can loop over the properties like this:

```
for (var key in obj.query.pages) {
    if (obj.query.pages.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var item = obj.query.pages[key];
        //do something with item
        //item.extract...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just care about the 'extract' part, you can try this:

```
Object.values(obj.query.pages).map(item => item.extract)
```

To get a list of all the values

Comment: i think, it will return an array.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the given JSON is a variable `data`

```
let uniqueID = Object.keys(data.query.pages)[0];
data.query.pages[uniqueID].extract
```

Will give you the desired result.